# Use cmd.exe in guest with vboxmanage

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

The [manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol) about `vboxmanage run` says:

```
run Executes a guest program - forwarding stdout, stderr and stdin to/from the host until it completes.
```

I have windows 7 guest in ubuntu host and try to use the command prompt from the shell:

```
vboxmanage guestcontrol  VmName --username Me run cmd.exe
```

The program executes, the welcome message is printed and the `$` is replaced by `C:\Windows\system32>`, however it doesn't seem that any of the input is passed to prompt. You can press enter, ctrl-m - it just keeps adding newlines as if it was incomplete input.

Have anyone been able to use the stdin from host to guest?

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

This is not a complete solution to your problem but it might help to find the cause of it! I have a similar problem and tested around a little. Maybe you can do the same tests within your setup so we can gather more information about the problem.

## About

As I said I actually have (almost) the same problem as you just with a reversed host/guest situation. My host is Windows 10 and my guest is Ubuntu. I want to run a Python script within the guest machine for a host/guest communication via Standard I/O.

I experience the same behaviour as you do. - The standard output of the Python script is shown within the Windows 10 host but I am not able to write anything to the standard input of the guest machine.

Therefore I built a testing environment which emulates the behaviour described in the VirtualBox manual you already quoted (highlighting added by myself):

> run Executes a guest program - forwarding **stdout**, stderr and **stdin** **to/from** the host until it completes. - [Source](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol))

## Testing Environment

The testing environment consists of the following two programs:

- VM Control: In the testing environment the VM Behaviour Emulator is called here. VM Control would normally call `VBoxManage guestcontrol ... run ...`
- VM Behaviour Emulator: When this program is called by VM Control a line is getting written to the standard output. If VM Control writes something to the standard input afterwards VM Behaviour Emulator will echo the input to the standard output.

#### VM Control (Built from parts of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx))

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace VM_Control
{
  class Program
  {
    private static StreamWriter vmComInput = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // Process instance for executable
      Process vmCom = new Process();

      // Path to executable
      vmCom.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,
        @"..\..\..\VM Behaviour Emulator\bin\Debug\VM Behaviour Emulator.exe"));

      // Process configuration
      vmCom.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      vmCom.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      vmCom.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
      vmCom.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
      vmCom.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

      // Setup EventHandler
      vmCom.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(VMComOutputHandler);

      // Start the executable in a separate process
      vmCom.Start();

      // Enable OutputDataReceived events
      vmCom.BeginOutputReadLine();
      // Link local StreamWriter instance to processes StandardInput
      vmComInput = vmCom.StandardInput;

      // Wait until the process finished executing
      vmCom.WaitForExit();
    }

    private static void VMComOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,DataReceivedEventArgs line)
    {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Data))
      {
        // Print received StandardOutput line
        Console.WriteLine(line.Data);

        // Provide some input through the StandardInput StreamWriter
        if (line.Data == "Enter something: ")
          vmComInput.WriteLine("... an input string entered by a StreamWriter instance.");

        // Another input through the StandardInput StreamWriter would close the application
        // at this point
        else if (line.Data == "Press enter to quit the application")
          Debug.WriteLine("Process finished");
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

#### VM Behaviour Emulator

```cs
using System;

namespace VM_Behaviour_Emulator
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string input = "";

      // Prompt user for input
      Console.WriteLine("Enter something: ");
      input = Console.ReadLine();

      // Echo user's input
      Console.WriteLine("You entered: {0}", input);

      // Wait until user quits the application 
      Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit the application");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }  
}
```

## Conclusion

While the testing environment works as expected (it can pass data to VM Behaviour Emulator through Standard Input) VM Control has the same behaviour as you described when calling `VBoxManage guestcontrol ... run ...`. It simply doesn't recognize the data written through Standard Input. The same behaviour shows when trying to run `VBoxManage guestcontrol ... run ...` from the host's command line.

So as I already mentioned maybe it is possible for you to build a similar testing environment. Maybe we will get more information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like [David Michael](https://superuser.com/a/1216178/515554) suggested, I've made tests. I've tried ubuntu guest on ubuntu host. In the guest I've created a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo write something to stdin
read a
echo you wrote $a
```

and I've tried to call it through the vbox `vboxmanage guestcontrol Dawg --username u --password 1qaz run  -- /bin/bash -c "cd; ./script"`. The first `echo` commands works, but the program hangs on `read`.

I guess the problem is not encoding mismatch between the platforms since they're the same in the test.

---

I guess it is simply not intended to work this way, or the question is more of a bug report for the development team now.